# [STRIPE CONNECT]: Test routing and account number invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, stripe-payments

I m developping a rails app, using stripe connect for my users.
In my test app using stripe test connect (Express mode), I don't manage to enter the right routing account and the right bank account for France.
Everytime I have the following error: 'Invalid routing number'
And the second think is that I don't have the choice to select a credit card instead of a bank account number.
Has someone a solution to test my Stripe connect with a working number or an other solution? 
The stripe documentation is not helping with that numbers...
Thks,
Samy

Comment: So in France, I believe you can *only* pay out to Bank Accounts (not debit cards).  Which is likely why you don't see the option.  In Test Mode, you'll also need to use test account and routing numbers for that country.  You can find those here: https://stripe.com/docs/testing.  Are you using those or are you trying to use real ones?  Real ones will not work.

Comment: Thks @korben, Ok I understand the fact that in France stripe connect only allows the bank account number and not the credit card. But the routing and account numbers in documentation for France account is not working...  routing number 111000000  and account number FR1420041010050500013M02606 . I still have invalid routing number

Comment: @SamyCha Express accounts can only be located in the US https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts so that's most likely why French bank account details are not accepted for them.

Answer (score 7):

When testing Stripe Connect payout integrations, you can enter the following US account info (any real bank account / routing number is rejected in test mode):

- Routing number: `110000000`
- Account number: `000123456789`

Answer (score 0):

For testing, to add a bank account to the test account, you would actually need to use a real routing number with a test account number. Stripe provides test bank information, though this is more geared for testing bank-based payment methods and not adding bank information to an account for payouts and will give the 'Incorrect routing number' error. Also, @korben is correct in that French accounts currently do not support debit card payouts, they must be done to a bank account.

Comment: Thks @BA-25, Ok I understand the fact that in France stripe connect only allows the bank account number and not the credit card. But the routing and account numbers in documentation for France account is not working...  routing number 111000000  and account number FR1420041010050500013M02606 . I still have invalid routing number

Comment: Ah, I see! So the issue here would be that attempt to add a routing number. EU bank accounts use the IBAN format and do not have routing numbers -resulting in the error.

Comment: Assuming you are creating an EUR French bank account for your connected account, among specifying external_account[object] as bank_account, external_account[country] as FR, external_account[currency] as EUR, you would only need external_account[account_number] which we can set to be the test bank account found on the below page FR89370400440532013000 (in the stripe docs it prefixes the number with DE rather than FR, though we change to FR as this is the country for the account in question)

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#account-numbers

Comment: Thks for your reply @BA-25 . I got in touch with stripe and they told me that for french account it is not possible to use credit card number for the stripe connect (to get the money from the customer). I adjusted my account as a US account and the following numbers for routing and account number in test mode are working fine now: Routing number: 110000000 and Account number: 000123456789

Answer (score -1):

Routing Number **required** for US only. Here is sample for creating account.

```
"routing_number":"111000000",
"account_number":"SE3550000000054910000003"
```